# Nodejs and socket.io Openshift 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

I have problem with socket.io connection in openshift.

The xhr-polling : http://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LWuQ0UY&sid=qMdDVygVfAYMbfRbAAAO responses status 400 bad request

i have searched before and tried some ways, but it is not working

Here is some ways i tried in client side for creating a socket

```
//Solution 1
var socket = io.connect("http://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:8080/");
//Solution 2
var socket =  new io('http://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:8000/');
//Solution 3
var socket =  new io('ws://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:8000/');
//Solution 4
var socket =  io.connect('ws://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:8000/');
```

Here is configuration in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "optimist": "latest"
}
```

Below is my code in server side

```
//Declare constants...
//End declare constants
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, IPADDRESS,function(){
console.log("Server listen in " + IPADDRESS + ":" + PORT);
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server,{origins:'demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:* http://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:* http://www.demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:*'});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('message', { message: 'welcome to the chat' });
socket.on('send', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('message', data);
});
});
```

Updated : Here is my declaration of PORT and IPADDRESS

```
var PORT = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT  || 8080;
var IPADDRESS = process.env.OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP || process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || 'localhost';
```

Where is my problem ?

Comment: We don't see the values of your PORT and IPADDRESS constants. PORT should contain `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`and IPADDRESS `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP`.Is that the case?

Comment: please try this. `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('http://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com:8080/', {'forceNew':true });
socket.connect();
socket.on('connect',function() {
 console.log('Client has connected to the server!');
});
</script>`

Comment: @SouravGhosh: It's not work. The message ''Client has connected to the server!" is not displayed

Comment: is it working on your local machine? I copied all your code and it worked fine on my local machine. also, can you please try removing the origin restriction in your code and try?

Comment: @SouravGhosh : Yes, it works on my localhost. But when i deploy to openshift. It didn't work. Maybe i will try in heroku .
I removed the origin restriction , but got the error about cross domain exception. 
Thanks for your support.

Comment: I uploaded your server code on my openshift today and it worked fine. (demo: http://sourav.eu.org/1.html). Please try multiple times if error appears as openshift free account shuts down after 24 hours inactivity. all code is same as yours. I just changed one line `var io = require('socket.io')(server,{origins:'*:*'});` http://pastebin.com/DAS6rtWr. I didn't get any cross domain exception. please note that the client web page should be an HTTP URL. like http://127.0.0.1/client.html. Don't load it from file://. Also check http://portquiz.net:8000/ to see if port 8000 is open on client side.

Comment: It's not work. I don't now . 
Here is my full code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/15137683b261fc3a0738bdcf09113614
all client files : chat.html and js file is in directory [root project directory] /  static .

Comment: @SouravGhosh : You can view it on : http://demowebchat-pydevelopment.rhcloud.com/chat.html